# Junit for ArrayList

Tags: java, junit

I would be grateful for some help in this problem
I have 2 classes I need to do Junit test for them. I think I did first one correctly but I have problem with second one with ArrrayList.

Firs class

```
package main;

/**
 * Class that stores the following
 * 
 * Customer Name:
 * Customer PPS:
 * Customer Email:
 * Customer Age:
 */
public class Customer {

    // Customer Name
    private String name;

    // Customer Pps Number
    private int Pps;

    // Customer Email
    private String email;

    // Customer Age
    private int age;    


    /**
     * Constructor that creates Customer object 
     * 
     * @param name name of Customer
     * @param Pps numeric Pps of Customer
     * @param email email of Customer
     * @param age age of Customer
     */
    public Customer(String name, int Pps, String email, int age) {

        if (name==null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be null");

        if (email==null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Email cannot be null");

        if (name.trim().length()==0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be empty");

        if (Pps<=0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not positiove Ppss are not allowed");

        if (age<18)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Customer mush be at least 18 year old");

        this.name = name;
        this.Pps = Pps;             
        this.email = email;

        this.age = age;
    }

    /**
     * Gets name of Customer
     * 
     * @return name Customer name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Gets PPS of Customer 
     *  
     * @return Customer PPS number
     */
    public int getPps() {
        return Pps;     
    }

    /**
     * Gets email of Customer
     * 
     * @return Customer Email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * Gets age of Customer
     * 
     * @return Customer age
     */
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

JUnit of First Class

The customer class should check the following before creating an instance of the class

The customer name is not empty
The PPS number is not null
The email is not empty
The age  of the customer is greater than 18

```
package test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import main.Customer;

public class testCustomer {

    Customer myCustomer;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    myCustomer = new Customer("Name1", 2, "Name2", 18);
    }
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }


    @Test
    public void test() {
        //fail("Not yet implemented");
        assertTrue("It can't be null", (myCustomer.getName() !=null));
        assertTrue("It can't be null", (myCustomer.getEmail() !=""));
        assertTrue("It can't be negative number", (myCustomer.getPps() >=0));
        assertTrue("It can't be smaller than 18", (myCustomer.getAge() >=18));

    }


}
```

Second Class

```
package main;

import java.security.InvalidParameterException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * The CustomerList class can Add, Remove, 
 * Find by Customer Name, Find by Customer pps, Find by Email and return the Total No. of Customers
 *
 */
public class CustomerList { 
    private ArrayList<Customer> list;


    /**
     * Constructor of Customer list object 
     * Creates empty Customer list 
     */
    public CustomerList() {
        list = new ArrayList<Customer>();       
    }

    /**
     * Add new Customer into list
     * There is not allowed to have two Customers with same id
     * 
     * @param newCustomer new Customer object 
     */
    public void add(Customer newCustomer) {
        for(Customer Customer : list)
            if (Customer.getPps()==newCustomer.getPps())
            {
                throw new InvalidParameterException("Customer with this ID is already added into list");
            }

        list.add(newCustomer);      
    }

    public void remove(int id) {
        for(Customer Customer : list)
            if (Customer.getPps()==id)
            {
                list.remove(Customer);  
                return;
            }
    }

    public Customer findById(int id) {
        for(Customer Customer : list)
            if (Customer.getPps()==id)
            {
                return Customer;
            }
        return null;
    }

    public Customer findByEmail(String email) {
        for(Customer Customer : list)
            if (Customer.getEmail().equals(email))
            {
                return Customer;
            }
        return null;
    }

    public Customer findByName(String name) {
        for(Customer Customer : list)
            if (Customer.getName().equals(name))
            {
                return Customer;
            }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Gets total number of Customers
     * 
     * @return total number of Customers
     */
    public int getNumberOfCustomers() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

JUnit for second class (trial)

The CustomerList class can

Add Customer objects,
Remove Customer objects,
Find by Customer Name
Find by Customer pps,
Find by Email
Return the Total No. of Custome

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import main.Customer;
import main.CustomerList;

public class testCustomerList {


    Customer myCustomer = new Customer("Name1", 2, "Name2", 18);
    CustomerList myCustomerList=myCustomerList = new CustomerList(); 
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        myCustomer = new Customer("Name1", 2, "Name2", 18); 
    myCustomerList = new CustomerList();


    }
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

        assertEqual(myCustomerList.add(myCustomer) myCustomerList.size(1));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests are bad written, you testing bunch of cases in one test, you should separate them for manner witch each case have it's own method. Correct code will be:

```
public class CostumerTest {
    private final static String VALID_EMAIL = "valid@mail.com";
    private final static int VALID_AGE = 42;
    private final static int VALID_PPS = 42;
    private final static int VALID_NAME = "Bob";


    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenNameIsNull() {
        Costumer costumer = new Costumer(null, VALID_PPS, VALID_EMAIL, VALID_AGE);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenEmailIsNull() {
        Costumer costumer = new Costumer(VALID_NAME, VALID_PPS, null, VALID_AGE);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenNameIsEmpty() {
        Costumer costumer = new Costumer("", VALID_PPS, VALID_EMAIL, VALID_AGE);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenNegativePPS() {
        Costumer costumer = new Costumer(VALID_NAME, 0, VALID_EMAIL, VALID_AGE);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenCostumerAgeIsLessThan18() {
        Costumer costumer = new Costumer(VALID_NAME, VALID_PPS, VALID_EMAIL, 17);
    }

}
```

It's properly written unit test for Costumer class, it's looks like live documentation and reads like plain english text.

In same manner you should write test for second class

```
      public class CustomerListTest {


        @Test
        public void shouldHaveZeroNumberOfCustomersWhenNewCreated() {
            CustomerList customers = new CustomerList();
            Assert.assertEquals(0, customers.getNumberOfCustomers());
        }

        @Test
        public void shouldIncreaseSizeWhenNewCustomerAdded() {
            CustomerList customers = new CustomerList();
            Customer customer = //valid costumer here;
            customers.add(customer)
            Assert.assertEquals(1, customers.getNumberOfCustomers());
        }

        //and so on...

        @Test
        public void shouldReturnNullWhenFindByIdInvokedWithNotExistId() {
            CustomerList customers = new CustomerList();
            Assert.assertEquals(null, customers.getById(42)); 
            //return null is bad practice better to return Optional<Customer>, Iterator, or Collection
        }

        @Test
        public void shouldReturnCustomerWithIdWhenItPresentsInList() {
            CustomerList customers = new CustomerList();
            Customer customer = new Customer("name", 1, "email", 20);
            customers.add(customer);
            Assert.assertEquals(customer, customers.getById(1)); 
            // this works because not overriden equals checks if it's same instance, 
            //you need to implement equals and hashcode in Customer class
        }

        @Test
        public void shouldReturnNullWhenFindByIdArgumenNotEqualsToStoredCustomersId() {
            CustomerList customers = new CustomerList();
            Customer customer1 = new Customer("name", 1, "email", 20);
            Customer customer2 = new Customer("name", 2, "email", 20);
            Customer customer3 = new Customer("name", 3, "email", 20);
            customers.add(customer1);
            customers.add(customer2);
            customers.add(customer3);
            Assert.assertEquals(null, customers.getById(42)); 
            // this works because not overriden equals checks if it's same instance, 
            //you need to implement equals and hashcode in Customer class
        }

}
```

You need to read something about TDD technique, with this skill you will write tests before the code. Best book about test driven development is 
 [Test Driven Development by Kent Beck](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530)